# Format million, billion etc without SI Prefix

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I need to show the millions, billions, thousands in Y-axis of D3 chart with 1 or 2 decimals without the SI prefix. I tried with,

```
d3.format(".2s"); // which shows 9.0M or 90k etc.
```

But i need only 9.0 or 90 etc. I can use .replace() and it will work. But looking for an builtin function in D3 which can help me.

Comment: May be I'm wrong. Do you want to display 9000 as 9.0 ?

Comment: @Ms.Tamil i need to display 9.0M as 9.0. In otherwords.. 9,00,0000 (9 Million) as 9.0